# How do I copy a string into the midlle mouse button from GUI in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, clipboard

I have a terminal script (let's call it `otp_to_xclip.sh`) which makes use of xclip to place a string into the middle mouse button clipboard:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
otp_to_terminal.sh | xclip
```

Now, to paste the string from the clipboard into the form where I need it, I need to

1. open a terminal
2. run `otp_to_xclip.sh`
3. center-click in the form to paste the string
4. close the terminal window

This is already an improvement wrt running the `otp_to_terminal.sh` and selecting its output on the terminal, but I would prefer something which avoids steps 2 and 4 too.

Answer (score 0):

A `.desktop` entry looking like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=otp_to_clipboard
Comment=otp_to_clipboard
GenericName=otp_to_clipboard
Keywords=pw
Exec=/home/myuser/.local/bin/otp_to_xclip.sh
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/myuser/Pictures/otp.png
StartupNotify=true
```

does the work! you can even place the icon into the launcher following the steps explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).